# replacing "window.location" with "window.open" having no effect

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I am using a click-to-call chrome extension that has a nasty habit of redirecting the call within the active window.

Obviously not the best for maintaining a workflow, and I'm not one to let an extension boss me around so I thought I'd make some tweaks, but have had no luck.

To my understanding, it should be as simple as changing `window.location` to `window.open` but it simply won't do anything once I make the change and reload it into chrome. Am I missing something?

````
    chrome.storage.sync.get(['disabled', window.location.origin], function(result) {
      checked = result.disabled;
      chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function(request) {
        switch (request.type) {
          case 'selectionVod':
            window.location = ("votel://" + request.info.selectionText);
            break;
          case 'selectionVcc':
            chrome.storage.sync.get(['vccPlatform'], function(result) {
              var vccPlatform = result.vccPlatform;
              if (vccPlatform && vccPlatform.includes('odcc')) {
                window.location = ("https://" + vccPlatform + ".providerdomain.ca/AGUI/make_call.php?phone=" + request.info.selectionText);
              } else {
                window.location = ("https://vcc-" + vccPlatform + ".providerdomain.com/AGUI/make_call.php?phone=" + request.info.selectionText);
              }
            });```
````

Comment: Make sure you're calling `window.open` as a function. If you're doing that it should work fine. [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/open)

Comment: Thanks for the response, I'm feeling a bit obtuse here. 

callLink.addEventListener('mousedown', function(e) {
      e.stopPropagation();
            var dialOut = ("https://vcc-na3b.8x8.com/AGUI/make_call.php?phone=" + phoneNo);
            function send2Dialer (){
            window.open(dialOut, toolbar=no, location=no,menubar=no,scrollbars=yes,resizable=no, width=400,height=400,left=430,top=100)
            };

Comment: Add a `"` quote before `toolbar=` and after `top=100`.